# Make Navigation Bar Opaque with solid bg color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I am trying to set a solid color for the navigation bar but it always appears translucent.

None of SO answers I tried seem to work.

I have tried:

In the App Delegate:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:89/255.0 green:196/255.0 blue:197/255.0 alpha:1.0f]];
```

In my main TableviewController:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:89/255.0 green:196/255.0 blue:197/255.0 alpha:1.0f];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;

}
```

I have also unchecked the `Translucent` option and checked the `Opaque` option in the attribute inspector.

Following is an image of what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

How do I make the navigation bar opaque with a solid background color?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Go to attribute inspector of for Navigation bar and remove check mark from translucent.

Please find in image.

[image]

Comment: I have done that already and mentioned it in my question. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Now it is opaque but it doesn't show the desired background color.

Comment: It works. I had changed the background color instead of bar tint color. My mistake.  Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I was also trying to figure it how to make Navigation bar background a solid color. I was trying to change background color from Storyboard - Attribute inspector but that was wrong option.

The **Bar Tint** color in the attribute inspector changes the background color of navigation controller.

[image]